# Angular 2 change input value on focusout with same value in a row

Tags: angular

I am trying to substract input value on focousout by 1. The strange problem is that it does the first time when I enter 100 and click aside(I get in view 99), but the second time I enter 100, it doesn't change although I can see in debug mode that the num property has been changed.

For this purpose I am just using one way binding and focusout event.

In html:

```
<input type="text" #numElement [ngModel]="num"    
(focusout)="distractByOne(numElement.value)" />
```

In Component:

```
distractByOne(val) {
  this.num = +val-1;
}
```

Comment: your code is working fine for me

Comment: Maybe I should have said what browser. I am testing in chrome.

Comment: I also used chrome. I just copied and pasted your code and it worked for me. Can you provide a code link (perhaps something like stackblitz) recreating the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `[(ngModel)]="num"`?

Comment: Got one https://angular-tobvym.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I wanted to avoid two way binding because I want to actually compare this.num with val, but if I have two way biding this.num will already be like val.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with ..

```
<input type="text" #numElement [ngModel]="num"    
(focusout)="distractByOne($event)" />
```

In Component:

```
distractByOne(val) {
  this.num = +val-1;
}
```

Hope it helps you ...

Comment: It doesn't change much, instead of numElement.value, I will just use $event.target.value but still get the same outcome. Again I am trying to avoid two way binding so I could actually compare the input value with this.num.